# daterangepicker.js selecting current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, daterangepicker

Anybody familiar with the **daterangepicker.js** plugin in Visual Studio .net?  It is actually a pretty good plug in, but with one minor flaw I can't get around.  When selecting the current date, it does not recognize it and does not change the date.  The user has to annoyingly switch to some other date and then back to the current date to get it to register.

Anyone else encounter this and have a workaround?

My date input:

```
define(function (require) {
'use strict';
var vue = require('vue');

return vue.component('field-date-input', {
    template: '<input class="form-control" v-model.lazy="displayValue" type="text">',
    mixins: [VueFormGenerator.abstractField],
    mounted: function () {
        var self = this;
        $(this.$el).daterangepicker({ autoUpdateInput: false, singleDatePicker: true }, function (start, end) {
            self.displayValue = formatDate(start);
        });

        var startingValue = formatDate(this.displayValue);
        if (startingValue !== null) {
            this.displayValue = startingValue;
            $(this.$el).data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(startingValue);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        displayValue: {
            get: function () {
                return formatDate(this.value);
            },
            set: function (newValue) {

                $(this.$el).val(newValue);

                if (this.value !== null)
                    $(this.$el).data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(newValue);


                this.value = formatWebApiDate(newValue);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This caused from `"autoUpdateInput": false,` and is documented on the [github for daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/issues/1442):

From the developer (Dan Grossman):

> Your callback function will only be triggered when a new selection is
> made. As the current date is the already selected date, clicking it
> again will not trigger your code. You can listen for the
> apply.daterangepicker event instead like in the "input initially
> empty"

Example Solution:

```
$('input[name="start_date"]').daterangepicker({ 
  "singleDatePicker": true,
  "showDropdowns": true,
  "autoUpdateInput": false,
  "autoApply": true
});

// HERE
$('input[name="start_date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
});
```